# Setting previous values to a state in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a div mapped so it would render any number of times according to data sent from the database. I'm setting a background color in the div which matches the id i'm getting from the back end.

What i want to do is set a background color to the new div i'm selecting and remove the background color of the previously selected div. I'm doing it like this

```
     constructor(props) {

                super(props);

                this.state = {

                    pollId: this.props.contents.post_poll_content_id,
                    temppollId: this.props.voted_id

                }

     }

     componentDidMount() {

                let el = document.getElementById(this.props.voted_id);

                if (el) {

                    el.style.backgroundColor = "#0b97c4";
                }

     }

     handleClick(id) {

                    this.setState({

                    pollId: id,

                    })

                let el = document.getElementById(this.state.pollId);

                if (el) {

                    el.style.backgroundColor = "#0b97c4";

                }

                let sel = document.getElementById(this.state.temppollId);

                if (sel) {

                    sel.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";

                }

                this.props.submitvote(vote_object)

       }

       render() {

                let {contents, submitvote, postId, voted_id} = this.props

                return (

                    <div className="txt_vote_bar_div" style={{
                        color: voted_id === this.state.pollId ? 'white' : '#9da0a4'
                    }} id={this.state.pollId}>
                        <p className="txt_vote_choice"
                           style={{color: voted_id === this.state.pollId ? '#FFFFFF' : '#6a6a6a'}}
                           id={"id" + this.state.pollId}
                           onClick={() => {
                               this.handleClick(this.state.pollId);

                           }}> {contents.content} </p>
                        <p className="txt_tot_votes"
                           style={{color: voted_id === this.state.pollId ? '#FFFFFF' : '#6a6a6a'}}> {contents.votes}%
                            (Votes:)</p>
                    </div>
                );
            };
        }
```

i have set the background color for the div using `temppollId` when loading the page and change the background color of the div when clicking on it using `pollId`.

My problem is this works for only one time as i cannot set the last selected div id to my `temppollId` in `handleClick` function . How can i remove the color of previously colored div when i select a new div.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't quite figure out the context here; need more details. What is `el`? `sel`? Where are the other divs? But a few observations: 1) you're calling `setState` in your `handleClick`, but you're setting the `pollId` to the same value, since you're passing in `this.state.pollId` as the parameter every time. 2) If your `pollId` state is never changing, why not just use the props directly? 3) Feels like you have a mix of React-style code and non-React code (doing `getElementById` and setting the color directly instead of controlling those elements from their parent component).

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the parameter `prevState` when calling `this.setState()` (reference below). You have to be careful when you're updating the state in react, you really want to follow their documentation. Otherwise, it can get wonky and buggy, and it's harder code to follow. Also, please be aware that doing direct DOM manipulation in react is also not best practice (i.e. avoid `document.getElementById()` at all costs unless you're mounting your entire app).

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

I would consider going through more of their documentation in general as well.